# How to create list within a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to have three columns in a dataframe containing  one row with each cell containing the list

**Input**

```
mylist1 <- strsplit(c("banana","tomato","NA"), ",")
mylist2 <- strsplit(c("orange","nut","tomato"), ",")
mylist3 <- strsplit(c("orange","nut","NA"), ",")
```

**Desired output**

```
mylist1   mylist2   mylist3
list       list       list
```

but at the moment I get a dataframe that splits the list into separate columns How do I create a list of lists within a dataframe?

**Current output**

```
structure(list(X.banana. = "banana", X.tomato. = "tomato", X.NA. = "NA", 
               X.orange. = "orange", X.nut. = "nut", X.tomato..1 = "tomato", 
               X.orange..1 = "orange", X.nut..1 = "nut", X.NA..1 = "NA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                              -1L))
```

Comment: `strsplit` in your input does not have any use, it does the same as `as.list(c("banana","tomato","NA"))` (for `mylist1`) or `list("banana","tomato","NA")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
df <- data.frame(row.names=1)
df$l1 <- list(mylist1)
df$l2 <- list(mylist2)
df$l3 <- list(mylist3)

> dim(df)
[1] 1 3
> df
                  l1                  l2              l3
1 banana, tomato, NA orange, nut, tomato orange, nut, NA
```

Another a more programatically friendly way is to first put them in a matrix:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(list(mylist1, mylist2, mylist3), nrow=1))

> df
                  V1                  V2              V3
1 banana, tomato, NA orange, nut, tomato orange, nut, NA
```

Comment: can you explain why it has to be placed In a matrix first?

Comment: No particular reason. That's just how the constructors work. For example `as.data.frame.list` has this line: `do.call(data.frame, x)` so it calls `data.frame` constructor on all elements in `x`. While `as.data.frame.matrix` preserves the structure of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. First, we put everything into a list, then we map a dataframe. Lastly, we spread the data to wide.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list(mylist1, mylist2, mylist3) %>% 
  map_df(., ~tribble(~col, .x)) %>%
  mutate(name = c("mylist1", "mylist2", "mylist3")) %>% 
  spread(name, col)
df
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   mylist1    mylist2    mylist3   
#>   <list>     <list>     <list>    
#> 1 <list [3]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
```

And each column contains a list:

```
df$mylist1
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "banana"
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "tomato"
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]]
#> [1] "NA"
```